# Is there a procedure to determine optimal location viewpoints with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I must visually cover a 7,000 ha area from observation points. Does anybody know a procedure using QGIS to determine their locations, minimizing the number of points and maximizing the viewshed?

Comment: QGIS https://github.com/zoran-cuckovic/QGIS-visibility-analysis "The plugin is intended for more complex modelling, such as the depth below the visible horizon or generation of intervisibilty networks between groups of points."

Comment: Already got that plugin, but the location of the points must be fixed beforehand. What I would like is the system to select those locations (e.g. for a given number of points) so the viewshed is maximized.